# rails, postgres and jsonb. query doesn't find records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I can't get my query to find relevant records.

here's my  test record:

```
model: Submission
column name: contents (jsonb)
```

record is created by: `Submission.create(contents: {ada: 'ada'})`

here's the query: `Submission.where("contents->>'ada'='ada'").first`

results is `nil`

record is in database and (lets assume record id=1)

```
Submission.find(1).contents[:ada]=='ada'
```

results in `true`

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your query. Your _sanity check_ appears to be problematic, though. I would _think_ that it'd return false because the `ada` key isn't a symbol. (Just ran a quick test locally using your example and I'm able to create/query as expected and your sanity check fails unless I use `contents['ada']=='ada'`.) Could you include your schema? Is there a chance your column isn't actually of type jsonb?

Comment: thank you for your reply, sanity check results in true as described and in false if done your way. column is jsonb according to pgAdmin (I used to have it as var char but when it started throwing errors realized I forgot to make it an actual jsonb)

Comment: this is part of schema for Submission:   create_table "submissions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "name",         default: ""
    t.string   "contents_old", default: ""
    t.datetime "created_at",                null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                null: false
    t.jsonb    "contents",     default: {}, null: false
    t.index ["contents"], name: "index_submissions_on_contents", using: :gin
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_submissions_on_user_id", using: :btree
  end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I'm still not exactly sure what's going on but the problem was in the fact that I was assigning a default values of {} in my migration. when this default assignment is removed everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, ref [`this`](https://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails)

```
Submission.where('contents @> ?', {ada: 'ada'}.to_json)
```

Comment: thank you Salil but your query also results in relation with no records in it